# Use portable VSCode with portable Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I downloaded [VSCode](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/releases/tag/4.1.20210417) portable from and [Git portable](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Afterwards I entered the following to open my VSCode's setting.json:
[image]

and inserted:
[image]

Problem is I still cannot perform some git task directly from VSCode, because it seems VSCode cannot find it.
Error Message from VSCode:
[image]

I have double checked if the git.path is pointing correct file:
[image]

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?
Thank you in advance. Best regards, Gunardi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also stumbled across this error today. It turns out that you have to **leave out the ending**. git instead of git.exe

```
"git.path": "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Git\\cmd\\git"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your path "...PortableGit\bin\git.exe" to "...PortableGit\cmd\git.exe" and it should work.